# How to skip first zero in the entry form in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

here is field name "phone number". i want to store data in the database table without leading zero when a user can input phone number like '01323442234' or '1323442234'.

input = '01323442234' or '1323442234'
store = '1323442234' (skip first zero)

Comment: just use `$phone = (int)$request->input('phone')`, but why do you want to drop the number if it's using laravel validation it will be more simple

Comment: i want to store phone with country code.. like county code '+880' and phone '01323442234' . so the number is '+88001323442234' which is invalid. i want '+8801323442234' this format

Comment: why don't use regex? I mean it's much more simpler using regex, if you force the user then you can use either client side js or use laravel validation regex example `\+[0-9]{0,10}` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-regex

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto You're begging for an overflow on 32 bit systems if the int value of the phone number is greater than ~ 4.29B

Comment: @Richard Ehm because i never encounter it. I think maybe it's different for each country, but mostly in my country it only need 10-12 digits I think, And I never use 32 bit for now, so it work out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$trimmed_phone = ltrim($input, "0");
```

`ltrim` will trim all the leading character from a string, no other characters will be removed.

doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of way to remove `0` from the first part of a string. 
If it contains only number, then cast it to `integer`

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

You can use left trim as follow :

```
$var = ltrim($var, '0');
```

Just use `+` inside variables:

```
echo +$var;
```

Multiple it by 1 :

```
$var = "0000000000010";
print $var*1; // prints 10
```

Note : If your string contains without number, then only use `ltrim`